# How to rotate a buffered image without cropping it? Is there any way to rotate a JLayeredPane or JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, rotation, bufferedimage, jlayeredpane

I had searched about it but I did not get straight forward answer.
I want a buffered image to be rotated but not cropped
I knew the new dimensions are gonna be some thing like this

```
int w = originalImage.getWidth();
int h = originalImage.getHeight();
double toRad = Math.toRadians(degree);
int hPrime = (int) (w * Math.abs(Math.sin(toRad)) + h * Math.abs(Math.cos(toRad)));
int wPrime = (int) (h * Math.abs(Math.sin(toRad)) + w * Math.abs(Math.cos(toRad)));
```

Provide me a method for that.

BTW is there any way to rotate a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`?

Intention:  adding to panels and layered pane and also saving it to file (saving the layered pane).

Or can we rotate the layered pane?

Comment: *"How to rotate a buffered image in java without cropping it ?is there any way to rotate a Jlayeredpane or Jlabel?"* Sure, but if the image fills the full width and height, the dimensions of the rotated image need to be larger. It's simple geometry.

Comment: *"Intention: adding to panels and layered pane and also saving it to file (saving the layered pane)."* That really explains nothing about why the images need to be rotated. But since you mentioned it, I would not recommend trying to serialize components themselves. Barring more detail, I would tend to write everything (included rotated images) to a larger image and serializing that larger image.

Answer (score 4):

> How to rotate a buffered image without cropping it?

You had already half of the work by calculating the size of the rotated `BufferedImage`.
The other half is actually creating the rotated `BufferedImage`.
You can do that by using [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)
and applying some coordinate transformations  before drawing the original image onto the new one. Furthermore, it makes sense to paint the "excess" area with some background color.

```
public BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage originalImage, double degree) {
    int w = originalImage.getWidth();
    int h = originalImage.getHeight();
    double toRad = Math.toRadians(degree);
    int hPrime = (int) (w * Math.abs(Math.sin(toRad)) + h * Math.abs(Math.cos(toRad)));
    int wPrime = (int) (h * Math.abs(Math.sin(toRad)) + w * Math.abs(Math.cos(toRad)));

    BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(wPrime, hPrime, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = rotatedImage.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, wPrime, hPrime);  // fill entire area
    g.translate(wPrime/2, hPrime/2);
    g.rotate(toRad);
    g.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();  // release used resources before g is garbage-collected
    return rotatedImage;
}
```

Here is a test example from the above code:

Original image
[image: original]

Rotated image (by 30 degree)
[image: rotated]

Answer (score 0):

> BTW is there any way to rotate a JLabel with an ImageIcon?

The easier way is to rotate the Icon, not the label.

Check out [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) for a class that does the rotation and recalculates the size of the Icon as it is rotated.

> Intention: adding to panels and layered pane and also saving it to file (saving the layered pane).

Don't know exactly what that means, but if you just want to save an "image" of the layered pane then check out [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/).